# HTTP Status 400 - The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, controller

There is some problem in it. as it gives Http status 400-
The request sent by the client was syntactically incorrect. when i submit. it doesnt reach to the controller. Kindly review and help.

```
<c:url var="addr" value="/productsPage"/>
 <form:form method="POST" action="${addr}" modelAttribute="productsmodel"  enctype="multipart/form-data">

<form:input type="hidden" path="productId" value="" />
<form:input type="hidden" path="vendorDetails" value="" />
<form:input type="hidden" path="productDetail" value="" />

<tr><td>Product Name:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="ProductName" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Product Description:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="ProductDescription" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Category:--
</td><td><form:input type="text" path="Category" name="categorylist" list="listcategory" />
                            <datalist id="listcategory">
                            <option value="Add New">
                            <c:forEach items="${all_categories}" var="all_categories">
                            <option value="${all_categories.categoryName}">                         
                            </c:forEach>
                            </datalist>                     

</td></tr>
<tr><td>Quantity/Unit:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="quantityPerUnit" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Unit Price:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="unitPrice" value="" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Size:--</td><td><form:radiobutton  path="size" value="1"/>L<form:radiobutton  path="size" value="2"/>M<form:radiobutton  path="size" value="3"/>S<form:radiobutton  path="size" value="0"/>NA</td></tr>
<tr><td>Color:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="color" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Discount:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="discount" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Weight/Unit:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="weight" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Units on Order:--</td><td><form:input type="text" path="unitsOnOrder" value=""/></td></tr>
<tr><td>Picture:--</td><td><input type="file" name="pictureLink" size="100" /></td></tr>

<tr><td></td><td><input type="submit" value="Save"/></td></tr>

</form:form>

</table>
```

Controller

{

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/productsPage"},method=RequestMethod.POST)  
public String ProductPost(@ModelAttribute("productsmodel") Products products, Model model,@RequestParam("picture") MultipartFile file1){


    System.out.println("In Post Products");

    return "products";
    }
```

}

Model 
{

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Products")
public class Products
{
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name="ProductId")
    private Integer productId;

  @Column(name="productName")
  private String ProductName;

  @Column(name="productDescription")
  private String ProductDescription;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="category")
  private Categories category;

  @Column(name="quantityPerUnit")
  private int quantityPerUnit;

  @Column(name="unitPrice")
  private BigDecimal unitPrice;

  @Column(name="size")
  private int size;

  @Column(name="color")
  private String color;

  @Column(name="discount")
  private BigDecimal discount;

  @Column(name="weight")
  private double weight;

  @Column(name="unitsOnOrder")
  private int unitsOnOrder;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="vendorDetailsId")
  private Vendor vendorDetails;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="ProductExtraDetails")
  private ProductExtraDetails productDetail;
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. I figure it out.

Category, productDetail and vendordetails are joined to other table, and have to add their ID's.
i.e productDetail.productID as path